# How to convert SBS 3D to Blue Ray 1080?

Tags: video, video-conversion

Can anybody help me to convert a SBS 3d movie to any format like `.mkv` or `.wmv` or `.avi` in a high quality format. I accidentally downloaded a movie and i dint know about the SBS 3D , now its very irritating the screen is spited into two. 
So any help would be appreciated what i can do now to get rid of the split or shall i convert it to any other format??

Thanking you all.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do it with for example a tool like [avidemux](http://fixounet.free.fr/avidemux/). Here you can find a tutorial on [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aSDCtXXMXLA) which shows you, how to do it.

But be warned. To convert this movie, the tool needs almost two hours even if you do it on a good PC.